# How do I insert a variable into a regex .match() assertion?

Tags: regex, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I would like to add a variable, 'example', into a regular expression assertion.

```
const example = Selector('xyz');

await t.expect(getLocation()).match(/^https:\/\/int-.*.example.com\/en\/example\/-\/  ** HERE SHOULD BE INSERTED A VARIABLE, 'example' ** \/$/)
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it using the [RegExp Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).